# How to prevent storing domain name in href = $('a#myId').attr('href'); in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

For example if

```
location.href = 'http://mydomain.com/en/'
```

and I have

```
<a href="my-file.html" id="myId">i am just a link</a>
```

so

```
href = $('a#id').attr('href');
```

for some reason Firefox, Chrome and Opera return: `my-file.html`

but IE7 will return:  `http://mydomain.com/en/my-file.html`

I tried this function with the domain-name but gives an error:

```
function str_replace(busca, repla, orig)
{
    str     = new String(orig);
    rExp    = "/"+busca+"/g";
    rExp    = eval(rExp);
    newS    = String(repla);
    str = new String(str.replace(rExp, newS));
    return str;
}

domain-name is not defined
[Detener en este error] rExp = eval(rExp);
```

Any ideas for how to prevent it???

Comment: Your `str_replace` function with `eval` is really horrible - in multiple ways from using eval to leaking globals.

Comment: please tell, what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Umex i need only the firefox, chrome and opera behavior

Comment: _Please_ look at [how to create a regex instance with `new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description). (No it won't solve your problem here, but `eval()` - really?)

Comment: i actually didn't want to use that function, it was just a try i use that function for simple strings and allways worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
//this will give you filename only
var chk = "http://mydomain.com/en/test.html";
var chkArr = chk.split("/");
var filenameOnly = chkArr.pop();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using eval in your code.

You can use `str = str.replace(/.*\//, '');` to strip everything before the last `/` in a string.